# Stacked bar from Table in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, stacked-chart, matlab-table

I want to create a stacked bar chart from a table. Here there is a MWE of the type of table I am looking at:

```
clear all; 

country1=rand(5,1); 
 country2=rand(5,1);
 country3=rand(5,1);
 country4=rand(5,1);
 country5=rand(5,1);

 date=1990:1994;
 T=table(date',country1,country2,country3,country4,country5);
 T.Properties.VariableNames{1}='date';
 T.Total=sum(T{:,2:end},2); 
 T{:,2:end} = T{:,2:end}./T.Total; 
 A = table2array(T);
 A(:,[1,end])=[];
 A=sort(A,2); 
 TT=array2table(A,'VariableNames',{'country1','country2','country3','country4','country5'});
TT.Date=T.date;
TT.Total=T.Total;
T_new=table(TT.Date, TT.country1,TT.country2,TT.country3,TT.country4,TT.country5,TT.Total);
T_new.Properties.VariableNames=T.Properties.VariableNames;
T_new.World=sum(T{:,2:4},2);
T_new.World=1-(T_new.country4+T_new.country5); 
T_new(:,[2:4,end-1])=[];
```

T_new

```
date    country4    country5     World 
    ____    ________    ________    _______

    1990     0.2933     0.29471     0.41199
    1991    0.31453     0.34511     0.34035
    1992    0.22595     0.29099     0.48307
    1993    0.26357     0.33336     0.40306
    1994    0.28401     0.28922     0.42677
```

**Type of Stacked BAR**

====================

Based on the `T_new` table I want to create a stacked bar graph. In the 'x' axis the chart should show the dates (1990,1991 etc) and for each date should be **one** stacked bar. So, for example, for `1990` there is should be one bar stacking the values `0.2933     0.29471     0.41199`

**Ideally**, in the stack bar I want also to include the labels of (country1, country2, world) for the correspending values.

How I can do that in matlab ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
bar(T_new{:,1},T_new{:,2:end},'stacked')
legend(T_new.Properties.VariableNames(2:end))
```

[image: stacked bar]

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided contains an erron at line:

```
T{:,2:end} = T{:,2:end}./T.Total

Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in stacked_bars (line 14)
T{:,2:end} = T{:,2:end}./T.Total;
```

since `T{:,2:end}` is a `(5 x 6)` matrix and `T.Total` is a `(5 x 1)` array

You can fix it replacing that line with, for example:

```
T{:,2:end}=bsxfun(@rdivide,T{:,2:end},T.Total)
```

Once fixed the error, an alternative way (with respect to the already posted answer) to plot the labels could be to use the [text function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) to draw a string in each of the `stackedbars`.

You can identify the `x` and `y` coordinate of the point in which to draw the string this way:

- `x`: for each set of bars, is the corresponding `date` (you need to shift that value a little on the left in order to centre the text with respect to the bar since `text` uses the `x` coordinate as starting point
- `y`: for the first label (the lower) could be simply the half of the height of the bar; from the second bar on, you need to add the height of the previous ones

A possible implementation of this approach could be the following:

```
% Get the T_new data
x=table2array(T_new)
x=x(:,2:end)
% Ientify the number of bars
n_s_bars=size(x,2)
% Open a Figure for the plot
figure(123)
% Plot the stacked bars
bar(T_new{:,1},T_new{:,2:end},'stacked')
% Get the names of the table variables
v_names=T_new.Properties.VariableNames

% Loop over the dates
for i=1:length(date)
   % Create the label string:
   %   country_x (or world)
   %   percentage
   str=sprintf('%s\n%f',v_names{2},x(i,1))
   % Print the label in the center of the first bar
   tx=text(date(i)-.3,x(i,1)/2,str,'Color',[1 1 1])
   % Loop over the bars, starting from the second bar
   for j=2:n_s_bars
      % Create the label string:
      %   country_x (or world)
      %   percentage
      str=sprintf('%s\n%f',v_names{j+1},x(i,j))
      % Print the label in the center of the first bar
      tx=text(date(i)-.3,sum(x(i,1:j-1))+x(i,j)/2,str)
   end
end
```

Over the loops, the following image is generated:

[image]

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: This `T{:,2:end}./T.Total`, is not an error if you have Matlab 2016b.

Comment: And also, I see you really like animated gifs :)